# How do I program many different conditions and actions

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to loop through the level 1 properties in the object `address` and test a variety of conditions and actions that are specific to the property with an if statement within the loop. So, I've added level 2 `condition` and `action` properties in an attempt to reduce the complexity of the if statements. The code below represents what I'm trying to do and doesn't work. Not sure how to accomplish this.

```
var address = {
  first: {
    value: "Joe",
    condition: "address[key].value.length === 0",
    action: "console.log(key + ' Not street1:' + address[key].value.length)"
  },
  last: {
    value: "Dirt",
    condition: "address[key].value.length === 0",
    action: "console.log(key + ' Not street1:' + address[key].value.length)"
  },
  street1: {
    value: "123 Blah Street",
    condition: "key === 'street1' && address[key].value.length === 0",
    action: "console.log(key + ' This is street1')"
  },
};

for (var key in address) {
  var condition = address[key].condition;
  var action = address[key].action;
  if (condition) {
    return action;
  }
}
```

Comment: In case, you must use eval to execute the condition

Comment: You condition variables are strings, not booleans. Remove the quotation marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use actual JavaScript in these conditions and actions

```
  first: {
    value: "Joe",
    condition: function () { return address[key].value.length === 0 },
    action: function () { console.log(key + ' Not street1:' + address[key].value.length) }
  }
```

I don't recommend `eval()` unless you actually need it.  Your sample code doesn't need it... but who knows what the actual application here is.  If you truly do need eval, you must be careful about what you are executing and how it's built.

Comment: I'd personally add how `condition` and `action` should be called: `if(condition())`. If someone is asking this sort of question then chances are that simply saying "don't eval" may not be obvious enough.

Comment: I never understood this stubbornness against `eval`. If that's enough to pose a security risk you have way, way bigger issues with your application, because *anyone* can simply press F12 and inject their own code at will through the development console.

Comment: @Blindy Regardless of potential security risks, avoiding `eval` will in most cases make code easier to read, maintain and debug.

Comment: This solution worked after I added the functions to the if statement:
 `if (condition()) {
    action();
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to evaluate the condition and action using [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
for (var key in address) {
    var condition = address[key].condition;
    var action = address[key].action;
    if (eval(condition)) {
        eval(action);
    }
}
```

I do however second [@Brad's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29465393/3558960) about trying to avoid `eval` and use actual code where possible.